# Trying to connect to Active Directory but getting the same error: System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException: A local error has occurred

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory, ldap

Here is the code I'm trying to run:

```
public static string getEmail (string id)
{
            string ldapPath = "LDAP://aa.bb.net";
            string ldapUser = "OU=someGroup, DC=aa,DC=bb,DC=net";
            string ldapPassword = "xxxx";

            DirectoryEntry dEntry = new DirectoryEntry(ldapPath, ldapUser, ldapPassword);
            DirectorySearcher dSearch = new DirectorySearcher(dEntry);
            dSearch.Filter = "(&(|(sAMAccount=" + id + ")(cn=" + id + "))(|(ObjectCategory=user)(ObjectCategory=person)))";
            dSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mail");

            SearchResult result = dSearch.FindOne();

            if (result != null)
            {
                string email = result.Properties["mail"].ToString();
                return email;
            }
            else return null;
}
```

I want to search for users using their ID numbers and retrieve their email (which is 'mail' property in this case). I know this is bad practice since the password shouldn't be in the code but for now I just want to try retrieving their email just to see if it works.

Every time I run it, I get the same error mentioned in the title. I tried configuring IIS where I set the Process Model Identity to Network Service, and configured my web.config as such:

```html
<identity impersonate="true" />
```

Here is the stack trace:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUHwC.png)

Any advice?

Comment: you know you can get the same / better results using `PrincipalContext` do a quick google search on the following `C# Stackoverflow PrincipalContext` this will be much easier especially if you are not familiar with `LDAP or AD`

Answer (score 1):

`The server is not operational` means that a network connection couldn't be opened to the domain controller.

You can use the telnet command line client to check the connection like this:

```
 telnet aa.bb.net 389
```

A blank screen means it worked. It'll give you an error if it doesn't.

Port 389 is the default LDAP port. But there are other options:

- 636: LDAP over SSL
- 3268: Global catalog
- 3269: Global catalog over SSL

If 389 doesn't work, then check them all and see which, if any, work.

But I also see other problems with your code. For example, this line:

```
string ldapUser = "OU=someGroup, DC=aa,DC=bb,DC=net";
```

The user should indicate a user, but this indicates only an OU. Also, there's a space in it. Maybe it's just a bad copy/paste, but I thought I'd point it out.

You can also indicate the `distinguishedName` of the domain in your path. I can't remember off hand if the DNS name of the domain is enough.

```
 string ldapPath = "LDAP://aa.bb.net/DC=aa,DC=bb,DC=net";
```

Comment: `"LDAP://aa.bb.net/DC=aa,DC=bb,DC=net"` does actually work. It's not usually needed to specify both, although sometimes it's helpful if you want to target a specific domain controller like `"LDAP://dc1.aa.bb.net/DC=aa,DC=bb,DC=net"`.

Comment: Oh Great, Thanks. I was not updated about this one. I'll delete my comment. +1.